# "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"? in loopback 3

Tags: loopback

i don't know why i have this error
when i executing the method in the loopback explorer gives the error
This is the .js file used in the project

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Puntoventa) {

    var app = require('../../server/server');

    Puntoventa.getAll = function() {
        Puntoventa.find({ where: { nombre: !null } }, function(err, punto) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            return punto;
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the model .json

```
"name": "puntoVenta",
"base": "PersistedModel",
"idInjection": true,
"options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
},
"acls": [],
"methods": {
    "getAll": {
        "accepts": [],
        "returns": [{
            "arg": "punto",
            "type": "object",
            "root": true,
        }],
        "http": [{
            "path": "/getAll",
            "verb": "get"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to a bug in sql query, you cannot use !null instead you can use neq given by loopback

```
Puntoventa.find({ where: { nombre: { "neq": null} } }, function(err, punto) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            return punto;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use { "neq": null} } and define callback in getAll().

```
 Puntoventa.getAll = function(callback) {
    Puntoventa.find({ where: { nombre: { "neq": null} } } }, function(err, punto) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null,punto);
    });
}
```